Why can hexadecimal python integers access properties but not regular ints?
Decimal (i.e. non-prefixed) integers in Python seem to have fewer features than prefixed integers.
If I do 1.real I get a SyntaxError: invalid decimal literal. However, if I do 0x1.real, then I get no error and 1 is the result. (Same for 0b1.real and 0o1.real, though in Python2 01.real gives a syntax error as).

I'm rather surprised to find that int has a real attribute, didn't know that before.

@MarkRansom: Actually, I think a lot of the numerics have these properties, it allows for nice polymorphism. You can get the real part of an integer, real, or complex number. I recently had to show my son how this stuff all worked under the covers.

It's because the 1. lead-in is being treated as a floating-point literal and r is not a valid decimal digit.
Hex literals, of the form you show, are integers, so are not ambiguous in being treated as a possible floating point (there is no 0x1.1).
If you use (1).real to specify that the literal is just the 1, it works fine.
The following (annotated) transcript may help:
>>> 0x1.real     # Can only be integer, so works as expected.
1

>>> 1.real       # Treated as floating point, "r" is invalid,
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    1.real
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

>>> (1).real     # Explicitly remove ambiguity, works.
1

>>> 0x1.1        # No float hex literal in this form.
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    0x1.1
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax


For completeness, the lexical tokens for numerics (integral and float) can be found in the Python docs:
integer      ::=  decinteger | bininteger | octinteger | hexinteger
decinteger   ::=  nonzerodigit (["_"] digit)* | "0"+ (["_"] "0")*
bininteger   ::=  "0" ("b" | "B") (["_"] bindigit)+
octinteger   ::=  "0" ("o" | "O") (["_"] octdigit)+
hexinteger   ::=  "0" ("x" | "X") (["_"] hexdigit)+
nonzerodigit ::=  "1"..."9"
digit        ::=  "0"..."9"
bindigit     ::=  "0" | "1"
octdigit     ::=  "0"..."7"
hexdigit     ::=  digit | "a"..."f" | "A"..."F"

floatnumber   ::=  pointfloat | exponentfloat
pointfloat    ::=  [digitpart] fraction | digitpart "."
exponentfloat ::=  (digitpart | pointfloat) exponent
digitpart     ::=  digit (["_"] digit)*
fraction      ::=  "." digitpart
exponent      ::=  ("e" | "E") ["+" | "-"] digitpart

You can see there that the floats do not allow for hexadecimal prefixes, which is why it can safely assume the . in 0x1.real is not part of the literal value.
That's not the case for 1.real, it assumes that the . is preceding a fractional part of a float.
A clever-enough lexer could, of course, detect an invalid decimal digit immediately after the . and therefore assume it's a method to call on an integer. But that introduces complexity and may have other problematic edge cases.

Interesting.  In Python 3 leading zeros are not allowed for ints but they are for floats.

@Mark, that may have something to do with the C method of introducing octal numbers, with 0777 for example. Although Python doesn't allow that, it does use things like sscanf under the covers, and this would likely convert 0777 into 255 rather than 777. As a side note, every C coder uses octal if they have a 0 literal somewhere in their code, a little known fact to those who insist octal is unneeded :-)

Silly me, octal 777 is decimal 511 rather than 255. Other than that massive brain failure of mine, the reasoning is still sound :-)

Oh the reason for no leading zeros is definitely the change in octal notation, they said so very plainly when Python 3 came out.  I think it's a stupid restriction though, and I hope there comes a day when Python 2 is far enough in the rear-view mirror that they could revisit it.

It's a good thing that there's no difference between octal 0 and decimal 0, isn't it?
